# Is it possible to determine MySQL replication "position" with a normal query?

Tags: mysql, replication, rds

I have a MySQL (RDS) database that is replicated from one datacenter to another. There is also a message bus which spans these two locations, and it carries messages when certain writes to the database take place.

The messages and the MySQL replication race between the two locations. We need to make sure we don't process the message before the write that it refers to has definitely made it into the replica.

At the moment we use custom "last updated at" field on the tables that are replicated. It seems like there should be a global variable we can use instead though -- something that monotonically increases whenever there's a write anywhere in the database, and is available at both the master and the slave.

Does such a variable exist? Do I need special privileges to read it?

If there is not such a thing, what would be the tradeoffs associated with implementing it ourselves?

Comment: You can get the replication file and position at the slave with `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`, but I don't see how it will help. Timestamps seem to be your friend here.

Comment: I was hoping for something like access to the binlog position. Since it's only useful in combination with the file name though, it doesn't satisfy the requirement to be monotonically increasing.

Comment: The binlog file *sequence number* (the digits after the dot in the name) and position, together, meet the requirement, so something like `((${seq} << 36)  | ${pos})` would support 2^28 log files of max size 2^36-1 bytes each without overflowing an unsigned 64 bit integer.

Comment: The binlog sequence number and position together do indeed give us what we need, but we couldn't figure out how to read them with a "normal" database user.

We ended up building our own solution using a pre-commit hook and a table that with a bigint for the value that has a single-value enum primary key, limiting it to exactly one row.